# How do I delete everything from a table, except 1 entry in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1062

So I have an import/export module for OpenCart, but it's wiping the entire product option table before inserting new data...

I need to develop support for the 3rd party product options module I have, but in the meantime--I figure I'd just stop it from deleting an important column in my product options table.

In the `product_option_value` table, I have 'product_option,' 'product_id,' 'quantity' etc., and there's one column named 'info' that I want to NOT wipe. The method is below:

```
function storeOptionsIntoDatabase( &$database, &$options ) 
{
    // find the default language id
    $languageId = $this->getDefaultLanguageId($database);

    // start transaction, remove options
    $sql = "START TRANSACTION;\n";
    $sql .= "DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option`;\n";
    $sql .= "DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option_description` WHERE language_id=$languageId;\n";
    $sql .= "DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option_value`;\n";
    $sql .= "DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option_value_description` WHERE language_id=$languageId;\n";
    $this->import( $database, $sql );

    ...more code...
}
```

I'm not that familiar with MySQL, but I want something to the effect of:

```
$sql .= "DELETE FROM `".DB_PREFIX."product_option_value` WHERE column != 'info';\n";
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I tried Michael's suggestion to use `UPDATE` and explicitly setting them all to NULL... but that returned this error:

> Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 1
>   Error No: 1062 UPDATE
>   `oc_product_option_value` SET
>   product_option_value_id=NULL,
>   product_option_id=NULL,
>   product_id=NULL, quantity=NULL,
>   subtract=NULL, price=NULL,
>   prefix=NULL, sort_order=NULL,
>   weight=NULL, sku=NULL, image=NULL

I tried taking out the primary key:

> $sql .= "UPDATE
>   `".DB_PREFIX."product_option_value`
>   SET product_option_id=NULL,
>   product_id=NULL, quantity=NULL,
>   subtract=NULL, price=NULL,
>   prefix=NULL, sort_order=NULL,
>   weight=NULL;\n";

but I get:

> Error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 1
>   Error No: 1062 INSERT INTO
>   `oc_product....

**Edit:**

Okay, so I removed the 'primary_key' field from the INSERT... and I got no error messages from the upload. But when I view a product that product options, I get this message the top of my page:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   /httpdocs/ocart/catalog/model/catalog/product.php
>   on line 418Notice: Undefined index:
>   name in
>   /httpdocs/ocart/catalog/model/catalog/product.php
>   on line 418Notic.... it repeats

Comment: what's the problem with your query. Seems alright to me.

Comment: OK, so do it.... You may need `<>` rather than `!=`. Go look up MySQL operator syntax in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure I understand:  You want to clear values from all columns in the table `product_option_value` except for the column `info` ?  If that's what you want, then the following may work.  Please don't run it before we're clear on what you're trying to do!

`DELETE FROM` syntax implies deleting from a table name, not a column name.  What you'll need to do instead is to `UPDATE` your rows to set all columns except the one you intend to keep to be either `NULL` or empty or their default value.

Don't forget to add a `WHERE` condition if you need to keep some rows as they are without modifying them!  Without a `WHERE`, this query will NULL out all columns specified in the whole table.

```
UPDATE product_option_value
SET 
  product_option = NULL,
  product_id = NULL,
  quantity = NULL,
  etc...
WHERE (some where condition if you need one)
```

Comment: Probably because you set `product_option_id=NULL, product_id=NULL`.  You cannot overwrite the primary key fields for the table.  Those will have to stay as they are, along with their associated `info` column.  If you don't know the key fields, use `DESCRIBE product_option_value;` to find them. Then rerun your `UPDATE` statement without NULLing the key columns.

Comment: @Michael - I tried removing the primary key field from the query (product_option_value_id,) and I get a similar error message. See above...

Comment: What's calling the `INSERT` query in your second error message?  You were only doing an `UPDATE` before.

Comment: @Michael - Updated with the latest error message... I think this is more complicated than I anticipated.

Comment: @Shango Without seeing the full application and database schema I'm not sure I can help much further.

Comment: @Michael - I greatly appreciate your help thus far; should you have it in you to help further, here is the model file for the import/export addon... just search for the word option and you'll see the relevant methods: http://wolfdesigns.com/ocart/admin/model/tool/export.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a second answer, taking a completely different approach which avoids SQL problems.

1. Export your table as a comma-separated text file.  You can do this with phpmyadmin, or MySQL Workbench.
2. Open your CSV in a spreadsheet
3. Clear out the columns you want to clear out.
4. Save as a new CSV
5. Import the CSV back into your database using phpmyadmin, Workbench, or the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` syntax.

Comment: This is a 3rd party import/export extension for Opencart. I'm trying to modify the code so that it doesn't wipe another column created by a different 3rd party extension. I need to modify the code for every import/export, not just a one time deal :/